# Magento 2 WYSIWYG Media image directive using admin url

Tags: magento-2.1, url, wysiwyg, media

Why is magento 2 creating directives for media images using the admin url?

for example when i add an image on category page WYSIWYG it adds

```
<img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/image.jpg"}}" alt="" />
```

but then magento parses it for frontend and is like this

```
<img src="https://domain.co.uk/admin/cms/wysiwyg/directive/___directive/e3ttZWRpYSB1cmw9Ind5c2l3eWcvQ29udmV5b3JfYmVsdHNfZmFzdF9kZWxpdmVyeS5qcGcifX0,/key/b67d0a8069ef28a8443e0bad6d912512704213d60e1d9021b1ec2b9dd34bf390/" alt="">
```

because its linking to admin the only way it will load on browser is if you are logged in to the admin. This also poses a security issue because it is disclosing the admin path on frontend.

I looked in vendor/magento/module-cms/Helper//Wysiwyg/images.php and looks like the function **getImageHtmlDeclaration()** generates this

```
   public function getImageHtmlDeclaration($filename, $renderAsTag = false)
    {
        $fileurl = $this->getCurrentUrl() . $filename;
        $mediaUrl = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
        $mediaPath = str_replace($mediaUrl, '', $fileurl);
        $directive = sprintf('{{media url="%s"}}', $mediaPath);
        if ($renderAsTag) {
            $html = sprintf('<img src="%s" alt="" />', $this->isUsingStaticUrlsAllowed() ? $fileurl : $directive);
        } else {
            if ($this->isUsingStaticUrlsAllowed()) {
                $html = $fileurl; // $mediaPath;
            } else {
                $directive = $this->urlEncoder->encode($directive);
                $html = $this->_backendData->getUrl('cms/wysiwyg/directive', ['___directive' => $directive]);
            }
        }
        return $html;
    }
```

I tried to use static urls for media but still no use so the only work around I can think of is to edit this function to use frontend url instead of backend/admin

any help on this would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: Images in the wysiwyg editor appear to use the 'admin/cms/wysiwyg/directive' URLs when you look at the tags in the 'Edit HTML Source' window,  but on the frontend you should be see a 'pub/static/wysiwyg/' URL for those same images.

Comment: the admin/cms/wysiwyg/directive is on frontend on my magento 2 install

Comment: I'm facing same issue. Magento 2.1.2 WYSIWYG is creating admin URL for images for me as well.

Comment: Any news on this?

Comment: Experiencing this same issue on Magento 2.1.3 - Originally thought it was an issue with a third party extension but even the editor on CMS Page models experience this issue.

Comment: After many hours on this last night, the best recommendation (certainly not a solution) on this is to click the "Show/Hide Editor" button before save. When turning off the WYSIWYG editor, Magento will convert the directive URL to the `{{media url="wysiwyg/some-image.jpg"}}` format we have come to expect in Magento

Comment: @DarrenFelton thanks you very much I really appreciate. It worked.

Comment: The below solution perfectly resolved the issue.
https://www.ayasoftware.com/magento2_mime_content_type_upload_image_failed

Answer (score 8):

This is a known [bug](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6138) which is still present in CE 2.1.5.

The known fix is to add `'add_directives' => true` to `getConfig` function of`vendor/magento/module-cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Config.php`.

The best way to do that is to write an [interceptor](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html).

1. In your custom Magento 2 extension's `etc/di.xml` file:

   ```
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
     <type name="Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config">
      <plugin name="add_wysiwyg_data" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\WysiwygConfig" sortOrder="30" />
     </type>
   </config>
   ```
2. `Vendor\Module\Plugin\WysiwygConfig.php`:

   ```
   namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

   class WysiwygConfig
   {
    public function afterGetConfig($subject, \Magento\Framework\DataObject $config)
    {
      $config->addData([
       'add_directives' => true,
      ]);

      return $config;
    }
   }
   ```
3. Install it `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
4. **Important:** after installation you need to re-edit the affected category descriptions and re-upload images.

Idea of this fix extension is not mine but [this guy](https://github.com/Talv). He also packed it all up on github for you to [download](https://github.com/Talv/magento2-wysiwyg-fix).

I tested it myself on CE 2.1.4 and it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is to update the `getImageHtmlDeclaration()` function in `vendor/magento/module-cms/Helper//Wysiwyg/images.php`

```
public function getImageHtmlDeclaration($filename, $renderAsTag = false)
{
    $fileurl = $this->getCurrentUrl() . $filename;
    $mediaUrl = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
    $mediaPath = str_replace($mediaUrl, '', $fileurl);
    $directive = sprintf('{{media url="%s"}}', $mediaPath);
    if ($renderAsTag) {
        $html = sprintf('<img src="%s" alt="" />', $this->isUsingStaticUrlsAllowed() ? $fileurl : $directive);
    } else {
         $html = $fileurl;
        //if ($this->isUsingStaticUrlsAllowed()) {
        //    $html = $fileurl; // $mediaPath;
        //} else {
        //    $directive = $this->urlEncoder->encode($directive);
        //    $html = $this->_backendData->getUrl('cms/wysiwyg/directive', ['___directive' => $directive]);
        //}
    }
    return $html;
}
```

This may not be the best approach, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue with CE 1.9
And here is the solution: the idea is trying to change variable $html (you can use Di, Plugin or Patch [packagist.org/packages](https://packagist.org/packages/vaimo/composer-patches))

**Magento\Cms\Helper\Wysiwyg\Images.php** line 180

`$html = $this->_backendData->getUrl('cms/wysiwyg/directive', ['___directive' => $directive]);`

replace to

```
$html = $this->_backendData->getUrl(
                'cms/wysiwyg/directive',
                [
                    '___directive' => $directive,
                    '_escape_params' => false,
                ]
            );
```

Refer : [github.com/PieterCappelle](https://github.com/PieterCappelle/magento2/blob/94dc250732745cd56b87a301322629b338e29b43/app/code/Magento/Cms/Helper/Wysiwyg/Images.php)

Answer (score 0):

In your custom Magento 2 extension's etc/di.xml file:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Observer\CatalogCheckIsUsingStaticUrlsAllowedObserver">
        <plugin name="cms_wysiwyg_images_static_urls_allowed_plugin" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\CatalogCheckIsUsingStaticUrlsAllowedObserver" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"  />
    </type>
</config>
```

Vendor\Module\Plugin\CatalogCheckIsUsingStaticUrlsAllowedObserver.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class CatalogCheckIsUsingStaticUrlsAllowedObserver
{
    public function aroundExecute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Observer\CatalogCheckIsUsingStaticUrlsAllowedObserver $subject, 
        \Closure $proceed, 
        $observer)
    {
        $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        
        $storeManager  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
        $catalogData  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data');
        $storeID = $storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId(); 
        $result = $observer->getEvent()->getData('result');
        $result->isAllowed = $catalogData->setStoreId($storeID)->isUsingStaticUrlsAllowed();
    }
}
```

Working for me!