# Magento 2 Wysiwyg editor adding admin/cms/wysiwyg/directive links to store url

Tags: magento2, url, key

I am adding {{store url="about-us"}} to CMS block page but it ends like below

```
http://192.168.1.72/pneumatic-plus-categoryprototype/admin/cms/wysiwyg/directive/___directive/e3tzdG9yZSB1cmw9ImFib3V0LXVzIn19/key/7924ccb3f612214d2ba914a766df997c69513aaa31020334484941ca784f5e24/
```

Why its adding such static fixed url.

Anyone page suggest

Comment: You Can Prefer This Link For this  >>  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154796/magento-2-wysiwyg-media-image-directive-using-admin-url

Comment: Thanks for your comment. it was helpful